# How to make a wordpress image header appear only on homepage?

Tags: wordpress, image, header

How do I make my image header only appear on my homepage? Also, how do I edit code in WordPress to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this wordpress function `is_front_page()` to for this kind of thing, Simply add if condition

```
if(is_front_page()) {
/*your header image goes here and you condition*/
}
```

You have multiple ways for doing this either you can use header.php or you can make a home page template and write this condition this your home page template.

Comment: appearance -> editor -> wp-content -> themes -> your active theme -> header.php

but its not a good practice to add code via wp-editor you use ftp